# Can a child process access memory from it's parent process?

Tags: windows, process

Developing a Windows app where one application will be launching another exe (background service) as a child process. Will the child process have access to the parent process' memory?

Comment: On Windows, a "service" is never spawned from another application, only from the Service Control Manager.  I'm guessing you meant a type of background daemon other than a service.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, Windows child processes run in a completely separate address space from their parent (There is no `vfork`).

Long answer: There are ways to arrange shared-memory, and there are the `ReadProcessMemory` and `WriteProcessMemory` functions usable if the process has the appropriate user context and enabled privileges.